# How to design IEntityTypeConfiguration classes for different databases in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I extract model configurations into separate `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>` classes for every entity. Sometimes I have to use different configurations for different database types.

For example, in PostgreSQL, I have:

```
public class PostConfigurationPostgres : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Post> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.Created)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("now()");
    }
}
```

In SQL Server, I have:

```
public class PostConfigurationSqlServer : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Post> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.Created)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    }
}
```

In my `DbContext` I have:

```
public class KnowDbContext : DbContext
{
    public KnowDbContext(DbContextOptions<KnowDbContext> options)
        : base(options){}
    public DbSet<Post>? Posts { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var provider = this.Database.ProviderName;
        if (provider == "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL")
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(KnowDbContext).Assembly,
                t => t.Name.Contains("Postgres"));
        else if (provider == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer")
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(KnowDbContext).Assembly,
                t => t.Name.Contains("SqlServer"));
    }
}
```

Is there any alternatives how to configure model for different databases without creating implementations of `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>` for every database type like
`PostConfigurationSqlServer`, `PostConfigurationPostgres` and so on?

Comment: One option would be to leverage a static class that the EntityTypeConfiguration could retrieve the configured default values or other provider-specific values from. The OnModelCreating is triggered statically on the first access of the DbContext in any case.

Comment: How do you apply entity configuration?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, Sorry, is question for me? If yes, I edit question and add code for my `DbContext`.

Comment: Well, your solution looks ok. Every providers has its own extensions and in common code you may have collision in extension methods. In common assembly you may have base  abstract classes for entities which have specific to database configuration. Other entities can be registered in the same way as you did that for Sql server.